# fplot with secondary Y axis

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

Is it possible to `fplot` a function on a secondary Y axis?
I found out about `plotyy` in Octave, and `yyaxis left` or `yyaxis right` in Matlab. But they do not seem to combine with `fplot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following applies to Matlab - I cannot give you guidance for Octave.
Futhermore I do not have R2016a so I could not test `yyaxis` (which is also not required in my given solution).

What about a workaround using

> [X,Y] = fplot(fun,limits,...) returns the abscissas and ordinates for
>   fun in X and Y. No plot is drawn on the screen; however, you can plot
>   the function using plot(X,Y).

So a complexe sample looks like this:

```
xmin = -2;
xmax =  2;

fh1 = @tanh;
fh2 = @sin;
[x1,y1] = fplot(fh1, [xmin, xmax]);
[x2,y2] = fplot(fh2, [xmin, xmax]);
y2 = 1.5 * y2; % rescale to get different min/max values than y1

plotyy(x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

You can even have different limits for the x axis if you want to.

[image: Test plot]